# how to edit a file to keep lines of same length only by using shell command

Tags: linux, shell, editing

I have a file with contents like below.

```
7f22cebc9330
600e98
7fff1814ff50
7f22cebc95c0
7f22cebc95b8
4002a8
7f22cebc95bc
```

You can see that some have 12 characters (eg:7f22cebc9330 ), and some have six (eg: 600e98).

How can I edit this file such that only lines with 12 characters are kept in the file, removing all the lines that are NOT of 12 characters length ?

So that my new file would look like this:

```
7f22cebc9330
7fff1814ff50
7f22cebc95c0
7f22cebc95b8
7f22cebc95bc
```

I mean by using shell command in linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually all the numbers of my file are in new line , but while posting this question they all appear in same line . How to make them appear in separete lines ?? Or please someone can edit so that the numbers are in different lines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'length() == 12' input.file > output.file
```

There are several tools that will allow you to edit the file directly (gnu sed, perl, etc), but doing so is a mistake.  Write the output to a new file, and use the shell to rename if necessary.

Comment: Hey, one more thing , how can i add "2 " to every line in this file now ??

Comment: `awk 'length() == 12{ print $0 "2 "}`, or `awk 'length() == 12' | sed 's/$/2 /'`

Comment: Where does the filename come in these commands ? Say i want to use awk 'length() == 12{ print $0 "2 "}

Comment: Just insert `{print $0 "2 "}` after the `12`

Comment: Also, I have already used awk 'length() == 12' input.file > output.file , so all of the lines have only 12 characters now.. All i want to do is add "2 " in front of each line of this new file  ..

Comment: `print "2 " $0`.  Or `sed 's/^/2 /'`